# Share full-size image from remote URL

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, swift5

I found this tutorial in order to let my users share images from my app:

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/118/uiactivityviewcontroller-by-example

Here is the relevant code:

```
let items = [yourImage]
let ac = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items, applicationActivities: nil)
present(ac, animated: true)
```

It looks like I need to pass a `UIImage` in the items array.

In my app, I show a feed of images. In the API call for the feed, each image has a thumbnail URL (smaller size) and a full-size URL. My app displays the thumbnail images in the feed in order to keep my app speedy.

This activity view controller is triggered when the user long-presses one of the images in the feed. The problem is that I want the user to be able to share the full-size image (which isn't loaded into any ImageView in the feed), instead of the thumbnail image.

How can I do this?

I've considered fetching the full-size image on long press by following [this tutorial](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-load-a-remote-image-url-into-uiimageview), but this causes issues in that the activity view controller doesn't actually show until the image is fully downloaded.

What else can I do??

As an additional question, would the same apply to if I wanted to let the user share a video (mp4)?

Comment: Do you want to just share the URL or download the image and then share it?

Comment: @PGDev If I wanted to download the image, that would require the user to wait while the image downloads. Is there a best-practice for UI in this case? What would normally be shown to the user while the image downloads, before showing the activity controller?